# Fully Tested Application Crash On AppStore Version

Tags: ios, iphone

Here is the story

->We have an app which is fully tested and we are stil testing and it works (we use booth adhoc and developer provision)

-> few hours ago we lunched application on appstore but app crashes right  after the splash screen

->We have extensive Anti JailBreak and Anti Debugger attach mechanisms.

->One of these mechanisms reuires that embeded.mobileprovision file must be in application resources

->I know as a fact ipa that i send to apple includes that file but does apple removes the provision before they release on the appstore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `embedded.mobileprovision` file is removed as part of Apples process of final signing the app for AppStore usage. You should have check existing apps that you download from the app store (e.g. from iTunes rename .ipa to .zip and unzip it) and you will find that not a single AppStore distributed app has this file.

So your mechanism is completely wrong in this regard.